# Android onListItemClick: How to get an object whose fields are displayed in the ListView item which was clicked?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayList` of objects of class `MyClass`, each of which has four fields (namely `firstItem`, `secondItem`, `thirdItem` and `fourthItem`), the first three of which need to be displayed in the `ListView` of a `ListFragment`. **For this, I have extended the `ArrayAdapter`, and overridden its `getView()` method, as follows**:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.myFragment_listview_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    MyClass myClassItem = getItem(position);//******But this method is inside Adapter

    ((TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.myclassListFragment_ListViewItem1))
            .setText(myClassItem.firstItem);
    ((TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.myclassListFragment_ListViewItem2))
            .setText(myClassItem.secondItem);
    ((TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.myclassListFragment_ListViewItem3))
            .setText(myClassItem.thirdItem);

    return view;
}
```

*But when the user clicks an item from the `ListView`, the `fourthItem` field for the object whose other fields are displayed as that clicked listview item, should be displayed (in a `TextView`) in a separate `Fragment` (`detailsFragment`).*

The program adds the new fragment on the click of an item from the `ListView` as follows, **But the question is that how do I get the value of `fourthItem` field for the `MyClass` object whose corresponding `ListView` item had been clicked by the user, so that I can set it in a `TextView` in the `detailsFragment`?**

In the mentioned first `ListFragment`:

The `ListFragment` implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks<List<MyClass>>`, which means that the `List` containing the `MyClass` objects is passed to the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks`'s `onLoadFinished()` method:

```
 @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<MyClass>> loader, List<MyClass> dataList) {
      customArrayListAdapter.setData(dataList);
      if (isResumed()) {setListShown(true);} else {setListShownNoAnimation(true);}
    }
```

We have `onListItemClick()` method, which instantiates the new `detailsFragment` to display `fourthItem` in it:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    showDetailsFragment(position);
}

private void showDetailsFragment(int index) {
    listViewItemPosition = index;
    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myActivity_frameLayout1, detailsFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get selected row item object from ListView by calling `getItem` method of Adapter using `getListAdapter` as:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   MyClass class = (MyClass)getListAdapter().getItem(position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `setTag()` and `getTag()` mechanism to make your views remember something, that could be an object an integer a string or anything you like.

set this in getView()

```
 view.SetTag(myClassItem );
```

use getTag() in onItemClickListener() to retrieve data from item

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   MyClass class = (MyClass) v.getTag();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your method like this

```
private void showDetailsFragment(int index) {
    String fourthItem = ((MyClass)getListAdapter().getItem(index)).fourthItem;
    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance(fourthItem);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myActivity_frameLayout1, detailsFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

After this you will have to change the type of parameter passed in `newInstance()` of `DetailsFragment` to `String` and simply display that.